# Mixed Effects model with and without nesting: assumptions and residuals?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

**1. Residual distribution for mixed effects model with nested random effects - why do they look like this? Does it matter?**

**Code:**

```r
lme.result <- nlme::lme(Data ~ Time.Point + Status + 
    Time.Point:Status, random = ~1|Time.Point/Sample.ID, 
    method="REML", data = df)
```

**Factors and levels:**

Time.Point: before, after

Status: control, stress

**Further description:** samples were taken before and after treatment, but it is unbalanced (e.g. some "before" samples that don't have an "after" counterpart and vice versa), so Time.Point/ Sample.ID is set as a random effect (I hope I have done this right).

I am interested to know if there is an effect of Status and an effect of Time.Point (i.e. treatment), and if there is an interaction.

**Question:**
When I run the above, and check assumptions (see question 2) I get this:

[image: model with nesting]

**When I remove the Time.Point from the random effects and just use `random = ~1|/Sample.ID` I get this:**

[image: model without nesting]

I don't really understand enough to know why the first residuals vs predicted looks like this with the nesting

**1b. Have I got the nesting right?**

**2. What assumptions do I need to meet for this?**
Am I right to check normality and homogeneity of variance like I would with a linear model?

I appreciate that these are a lot of questions and that these have been asked in one way or another on here before, but it feels like the more I read, the more confused I am.

Edit: removed another question that was semi-related but locked the post.

Comment: Please describe the design of the experiment in more detail, incl. (a) how many measurements per Sample.ID at each Time.Point and (b) how Status is assigned to samples.